# how to convert column in this way in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

original data is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [1]*4 + [3]*5,
                 'B': [1.5]*2 + [2]*4 + [1.5]*5 + [3.2]*4})
```

how can I convert column `A` and `B` to:
[image]

and rule of `A_con` and `B_con` is:

A_con[0]=0; if(A[i]>A[i-1], A_con[i]=True, if(A[i]==A[i-1] && A_con[i-1]==True, A_con[i]=True, A_con[i]=False))

rule of days_A and days_B is:

if(A_con[i]==True, days_A[i]=days_A[i-1]+1, days_A[i]=0)

Comment: Could you properly format your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `diff` method takes the difference between the current row and the row above it. Anything positive will make `A_con` True. The tricky part is when the difference is 0. When 0, the immediate above value can take it's place. This is done using the `replace` with the `ffill` method. That takes care of `A_con` and `B_con`

For the days columns, we take an approach where we begin by taking a cumulative sum over the entire column of the `A_con` column (True values evaluate to 1) with `df['A_con'].cumsum()`. This obviously over counts as we must reset to 0 for any False values in `A_con` and begin counting again when True.

To do this, the entire cumulative sum is subtracted whenever `A_con` is False. But, when `A_con` is True, only the accumulation up to the last False needs to be subtracted so that the counting can continue. This is done again by replacing all the True values (now evaluated as 0 with `1 - a_cum.diff()`) by forward filling with the last cumulative sum when `A_con` was False.

```
# create a little more data to test
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [1]*4 + [3]*5 + [2.2]*3 + [2.4]*3,
                 'B': [1.5]*2 + [2]*4 + [1.5]*5 + [3.2]*4 + [2.2]*3 + [2.4]*3})

df['A_con'] = df['A'].diff().replace(0, method='ffill') > 0
a_cum = df['A_con'].cumsum()
a_cum_sub = (a_cum * (1 - a_cum.diff())).replace(0, method='ffill').fillna(0)
df['days_A'] = a_cum - a_cum_sub

df['B_con'] = df['B'].diff().replace(0, method='ffill') > 0
b_cum = df['B_con'].cumsum()
b_cum_sub = (b_cum * (1 - b_cum.diff())).replace(0, method='ffill').fillna(0)
df['days_B'] = b_cum - b_cum_sub
```

With output

```
      A    B  A_con  days_A  B_con  days_B
0   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
1   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
2   1.0  2.0  False     0.0   True     1.0
3   2.0  2.0   True     1.0   True     2.0
4   2.0  2.0   True     2.0   True     3.0
5   2.0  2.0   True     3.0   True     4.0
6   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
7   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
8   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
9   1.0  1.5  False     0.0  False     0.0
10  3.0  1.5   True     1.0  False     0.0
11  3.0  3.2   True     2.0   True     1.0
12  3.0  3.2   True     3.0   True     2.0
13  3.0  3.2   True     4.0   True     3.0
14  3.0  3.2   True     5.0   True     4.0
15  2.2  2.2  False     0.0  False     0.0
16  2.2  2.2  False     0.0  False     0.0
17  2.2  2.2  False     0.0  False     0.0
18  2.4  2.4   True     1.0   True     1.0
19  2.4  2.4   True     2.0   True     2.0
20  2.4  2.4   True     3.0   True     3.0
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept answer and upvote :)